# Merge files using a common column value

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to join these 2 files : File 1 (1 million lines) and File 2 (10,000 lines) in new File 3 (should be 1 million lines) using an `awk` command

File 1 :

```
 471808241 29164840 1 10001 156197396 
 471722917 21067410 1 31001 135961856 
 471941441 20774160 1 7001  180995072 
 471568655 29042630 1 15001 157502996 
 471524711 20716360 1 4001  180226817 
 471873918 29583520 1 2001  128567298 
 471568650 29042631 1 15002 157502910
```

File 2

```
610146 156197396 
531101 135961856 
704011 180226817 
502216 128567298 
707012 180995072 
615246 157502996 
685221 157502910
```

Desired output :

```
471808241 29164840 1 10001 156197396 610146 
471722917 21067410 1 31001 135961856 531101 
471941441 20774160 1 7001  180995072 707012 
471568655 29042630 1 15001 157502996 615246 
471524711 20716360 1 4001  180226817 704011 
471873918 29583520 1 2001  128567298 502216 
471568650 29042631 1 15002 157502910 685221
```

Comment: Crosspost: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347645/merge-files-using-a-common-column-value

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind sorting the files you could use `join` (although it might not be practical for your case, it's fun to see how it might be done)

First sort `File 2` on the common number field

```
sort -k2 "File 2" > file2clean
```

Then you can `join` the two files

```
sort -k5 "File 1" | join -a 1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 0 2.1 -1 5 -2 2 - file2clean | tee "File 3"
```

#### Notes

- `-a 1` print the lines in `File 1` that can't be paired (since this file has more lines, I assume that's what you want)
- `-o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 0 2.1` field order for the output line - the field we join on is `0`, and `1.1` is the first field of the first file and so on
- `-1 5 -2 2` join on the 5th field of the first file and the 2nd field of the second file
- `- file2clean` here `-` represents standard input passed along the pipeline, ie the sorted version of `File 1`

When done you can delete the intermediate `file2clean`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how efficient it will be for files of the size you mention, but since you asked for an `awk` solution it's really just a matter of creating a lookup table from the second file and then using the last field of the first file to key into it e.g.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} {$(NF+1) = a[$NF]} 1' file2 file1 > file3
```

Note that you don't specify what is to be done in the case that there is no match - in this case, it will add an empty field. If that's not the desired behavior, you can test whether `$NF` exists in `a` first.

Comment: when i use this awk command inside expect command i got the file3 empty i don't know why !! any help